# Hive - SELECT inside WHEN clause of CASE function gives an error

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, subquery

I am trying to write a query in Hive with a Case statement in which the condition depends on one of the values in the current row (whether or not it is equal to its predecessor). I want to evaluate it on the fly, this way, therefore requiring a nested query, not by making it another column first and comparing 2 columns. (I was able to do the latter, but that's really second-best). Does anyone know how to make this work?
Thanks.

#### My query:

```
SELECT * ,
CASE 
    WHEN  
        (SELECT lag(field_with_duplicates,1)  over (order  by field_with_duplicates) FROM my_table b
        WHERE b.id=a.id)  =  a.field_with_duplicates
        THEN “Duplicate”
        ELSE “” 
END as Duplicate_Indicator
FROM my_table a
```

#### Error:

java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'lag' '(' in expression specification; line 4 pos 9

#### Notes:

- The reason I needed the complicated 'lag' function  is that the unique Id's in the table are not consecutive, but I don't think that's where it's at: I tested by substituting another simpler inner query and got the same error message.
- Speaking of 'duplicates', I did search on this issue before posting, but the only SELECT's inside CASE's I found were in the THEN statement, and if that works the same, it suggests mine should work too.

Comment: Why are you using a sub-query?  Rather than just `CASE WHEN LAG(blah) OVER (blah) = a.field_with_duplicates THEN ...`?

Comment: What can I say. You're right. That did it. I didn't dare to try that because I thought I needed the whole query to match the indices. Thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the subquery inside CASE:

```
SELECT a.* ,
     CASE 
         WHEN  prev_field_with_duplicates = field_with_duplicates 
         THEN “Duplicate”
         ELSE “” 
     END as Duplicate_Indicator
FROM (select a.*,
             lag(field_with_duplicates,1)  over (order  by field_with_duplicates) as prev_field_with_duplicates 
        from my_table a
     )a
```

or even you can use lag() inside CASE instead without subquery at all (I'm not sure if it will work in all Hive versions ):

```
 CASE 
     WHEN  lag(field_with_duplicates,1)  over (order  by field_with_duplicates) = field_with_duplicates 
     THEN “Duplicate”
     ELSE “” 
 END as Duplicate_Indicator
```

Comment: Yes, the latter is what I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MatBailie for the answer in his comment. Don't I feel silly...

Resolved